# Most popular architecture used with dotnet

Tags: .net, architecture

What are the most popular architecture with dotnet? Right now i am using ASP.NET MVC, but i want to increase my work area with more architecture.Please provide me detail and links.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Onion architecture.](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/)
[Sharp architecture.](http://code.google.com/p/sharp-architecture/) (it's a framework actually)

Lately - there's buzz about [CQRS](http://blog.fohjin.com/blog/2009/11/12/CQRS_a_la_Greg_Young).

I would like to add [Domain Driven Design](http://domaindrivendesign.org/) but it's not an architecture either (despite that it seriously influences it). Because it's popularity increases.

Answer (score 2):

Depends of your needs, you need to discover your requisites and later design the architecture. Look at:
[Do you have any good examples of "architecture for architecture's sake"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473088/do-you-have-any-good-examples-of-architecture-for-architectures-sake)

I suppose SOA or n-tier (witout the UI) are the most popular for back-end. And for clients: asp.net (with mvp pattern), silverlight (with mvvm pattern) or heavy client with any pseudoMVC.

Comment: Thanks @@pablocastilla... i am going to start work on distribute application(It will working on LAN).i mean server and satellite model. So which architecture should use?

Comment: just wanted to add SOA and mvp mvvm mwhateverm ones. :)

Comment: server and satellite are two different application and i want to use WCF to communicate server and satellite.Please help me to grow my concept with the help of your gr88 idea's

Comment: well, SOA is more than technology, you should divide your business into autonomous and independent services which are orquestated by another ones. It is a huge architecture oriented for really big, or systems that will became big. 

If you have two systems that need to be connected make them totally independent and put somekind of orchestration on it (for example wwf 4.0).

WCF is a really good choice for implementing web services.

We just dont know the problem as you, just isolate your domains, do not make spaghetty and so on...

Answer (score 0):

NDepend documentation comes with some pretty cool online documentation / white books concerning architecture of .NET code:

[Advices on partitioning code through .NET assemblies](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2008/12/08/advices-on-partitioning-code-through-net-assemblies.aspx)

[Control Components Dependencies to gain Clean Architecture](http://www.theserverside.net/tt/articles/showarticle.tss?id=ControllingDependencies)

[Re-factoring, Re-Structuring and the cost of Levelizing](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2009/02/15/re-factoring-re-structuring-and-the-cost-of-levelizing.aspx)

[Evolutionary Design and Acyclic componentization](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2009/02/22/evolutionary-design-and-acyclic-componentization.aspx)

[Layering, the Level metric and the Discourse of Method](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2008/02/10/layering-the-level-metric-and-the-discourse-of-method.aspx)

[Fighting Fabricated Complexity](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2009/06/28/fighting-fabricated-complexity.aspx)